# How to parse a delimited string using the index of the delimiter in xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a delimited string which looks like below

```
FirstName&amp;LastName&amp;Address1&amp;Address2&amp;City&amp;State&amp;country&amp;
```

I need to split the string based on the index of occurrence of the delimiter.

Say, if i need the first four values in the string, i should get the output in 
two different variables, where the first variable should have the string with 
first four values and the second variable having the remaining string.

I don't want to use exslt or any other extensions.
Please help me with a simple solution.

```
    Input:

    <xsl:variable name="index" select='4' />

<xsl:variable name="delimitedString" select='FirstName&amp;LastName&amp;Address1&amp;Address2&amp;City&amp;State&amp;country&amp;' />

Output:

<xsl:variable name="requiredString">
FirstName&amp;LastName&amp;Address1&amp;Address2&amp;
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="remainingString">
City&amp;State&amp;country&amp;
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a straight-forward XSLT 1.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pSplitIndex" select="4"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="splitAt">
  <xsl:param name="pLeft" select="''"/>
  <xsl:param name="pRight" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pSplitAt" select="$pSplitIndex"/>
  <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="'&amp;'"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=
     "not(string-length($pRight))
     or
      not(contains($pRight, $pDelim))
     ">
     <t1>
       <xsl:value-of select="concat($pLeft, $pRight)"/>
     </t1>
     <t2/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$pSplitAt = 0">
       <t1><xsl:value-of select="$pLeft"/></t1>
       <t2><xsl:value-of select="$pRight"/></t2>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="splitAt">
         <xsl:with-param name="pLeft" select=
          "concat($pLeft, substring-before($pRight, $pDelim), $pDelim)
          "/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pRight"
          select="substring-after($pRight, $pDelim)"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pSplitAt" select="$pSplitAt -1"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select="$pDelim"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>FirstName&amp;LastName&amp;Address1&amp;Address2&amp;City&amp;State&amp;country&amp;</t>
```

**produces the required two strings that result from splitting `/t/text()` at the fourth `&amp;` delimiter**:

```
<t1>FirstName&amp;LastName&amp;Address1&amp;Address2&amp;</t1>
<t2>City&amp;State&amp;country&amp;</t2>
```

You can define a variable, say `vrtfSplitResult` whose body is the result of applying templates to the text node containing the string. Then, if you can use the `xxx:node-set()` extension, the two variables you want to define are:

```
<xsl:variable name="requiredString" 
     select="xxx:node-set($vrtfSplitResult)/*/t1">

<xsl:variable name="remainingString" 
     select="xxx:node-set($vrtfSplitResult)/*/t2">
```

**In case you are not allowed to use even the `xxx:node-set()` extension function**, then you should use a similar, named template: `getStartingString`. This has pretty much the logic of the `splitAt` template above:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pSplitIndex" select="4"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:variable name="vrequiredString">
    <xsl:call-template name="getStartingString"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable name="vremainingString" select=
    "substring-after(.,$vrequiredString)"/>

   <t>
     <t1><xsl:value-of select="$vrequiredString"/></t1>
     <t2><xsl:value-of select="$vremainingString"/></t2>
   </t>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="getStartingString">
  <xsl:param name="pLeft" select="''"/>
  <xsl:param name="pRight" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pSplitAt" select="$pSplitIndex"/>
  <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="'&amp;'"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=
     "not(string-length($pRight))
     or
      not(contains($pRight, $pDelim))
     ">
       <xsl:value-of select="$pLeft"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$pSplitAt = 0">
       <xsl:value-of select="$pLeft"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="getStartingString">
         <xsl:with-param name="pLeft" select=
          "concat($pLeft, substring-before($pRight, $pDelim), $pDelim)
          "/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pRight"
          select="substring-after($pRight, $pDelim)"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pSplitAt" select="$pSplitAt -1"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select="$pDelim"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced again**:

```
<t>
    <t1>FirstName&amp;LastName&amp;Address1&amp;Address2&amp;</t1>
    <t2>City&amp;State&amp;country&amp;</t2>
</t>
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. I think you could remove the copy&paste `t1` and `t2` elements from your second solution.